# install_fastcgi.sh is missing on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nginx, mysql, ubuntu-18.04, hhvm

I am trying to configure hhvm, nginx and mysql in my ubuntu 18.04 system following the following tutorials

1. [Tutorial: How to install Facebook’s HHVM on Ubuntu 18.04](https://medium.com/@AlyShmahell/https-medium-com-alyshmahell-tutorial-how-to-install-hhvm-for-hack-php-development-on-ubuntu-18-04-24cfc11e1e94)
2. [How To Install HHVM with Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hhvm-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

but after installing hhvm using `sudo apt-get install hhvm` I am not able to find `/usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh` hhvm directory itself is not there inside /usr/share

```
grep find install_fastcgi.sh
```

results grep: install_fastcgi.sh: No such file or directory

and  `which hhvm` results `/usr/bin/hhvm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path is `/opt/hhvm/4.55.0/share/hhvm` and not `/usr/share/hhvm`. Those reference tutorials are outdated.